# How to count number of times a tag was used and to display it in html?

Tags: python, django, count

I want to count the number of times a tag was used and to display it.
I tried this solution, but it displays then the number of tags in a post.
I understand that i counts like that, because its looking into post for the number of tags used.
But i don´t understandt how to tell him that he has to look at all posts.
When i try `posts.tag.count`, then it shows nothing.

The .html file:

```
 <h1 class="card-title">{{ post.title }}</title></h1>
                <p class="card-text text-muted h6">{{ post.author }} | {{ post.created_on | date:"d M Y"}} | Tag:
                    {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
                        <a class="mycardtext" href="{% url 'tag' tag.slug %}"> {{ tag.name }} {{ post.tags.count }} </a>
                    {% empty %}
                      None
                    {% endfor %}
                    </p>
```

I also tried just {{tag.count}}, but it also shows nothing.

With `{{ tag | length}}` i tried it also, but of course it then shows the length of the tag an not the number of times.

When i try `{{post.tags | length}}` then it displays an 0

Models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE,related_name='blog_posts')
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now= True)
    content = RichTextField(config_name='awesome_ckeditor')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
    tags = TaggableManager()
```

Views.py

```
def tag(request, slug):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {"post_list": posts, "slug": tag})
```

Comment: Did you try `{{ posts.tag.count }}` ?

Comment: Yes, i tried that also. Then it shows nothing

Comment: Are you trying to show the number of tags of the current post ?

Comment: No, of the current post i can show it with `{{ post.tags.count }}`
I want to show the number of times the tag was used in all posts.

Comment: And with `{{posts.tag | length}}` it also shows 0

Comment: show your models

Comment: I added my models and my views

Comment: @UrosDobricic See my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show how many times a tag has been used in any post, then you will have to create a custom filter, which is basically a function that you can call within the template.

Create a folder called `templatetags` in the same directory of the current app

```
my_app
======

    models.py
    views.py
    templatetags
        __init__.py
        app_tags.py


app_tags.py
===========

from my_app.models import *
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='count_tags_usage')
def count_tags_usage(tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in = [tag])
    return posts.count()


html
====

<html>
    {% load app_tags %}
    <head> .... </head>
    <body>
        ....
        <a class="mycardtext" href="{% url 'tag' tag.slug %}">
           {{ tag.name }} {{ tag|count_tags_usage }}
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It says : invalid filter count_tags_usage

Comment: I think i have to register the library

Comment: Replace `@register.filter` with `@register.filter(name='count_tags_usage')` and see if it works

Comment: Now it says app_tags is not a registered tag library

Comment: I think you did not import the `Post` model in `app_tags`

Comment: I did that, i saw that was missing

Comment: Open the Django shell and try to import `app_tags`. If there are errors there they will be shown. `>>> from my_app.templatetags import app_tags`

Comment: Ok, i reloaded the server. Now it says: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'blog.templatetags.app_tags': No module named 'blog.templatetags.models'

Comment: It's not `blog.templatetags` its just `blog`. It should be something like `from blog.models import *`

Comment: Thats it, thanks a lot. Great help!!! I didn´t see that i specified .models. 
I changed it to blog.models